# verbatim subscript in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, verbatim

I want to produce a formula in Math-Mode which is something like

```
\pi_{film_title}(\sigma_{release_year > 2006}(film))
```

where `film_title`, `release_year`, and `film` are in verbatim
so far I was using the `alltt` package, but the acclaimed `\sb` only produces subscripts in the usual math mode font.

Any tips for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use `\_` to get `_` (the actual appearance depends on the font unless you have redefined `\_` to use a rule, but either way the markup is:

```
\pi_{\mathtt{film\_title}}
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use the `alltt` environment for this. The simplest way is to give up the `_` character for subscripts and using `\sb` in its place:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=\string"715F }
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\(\pi\sb\texttt{film_title}(\sigma\sb\texttt{release_year > 2006}(\texttt{film}))\)


\(\pi\sb\mathtt{film_title}(\sigma\sb\mathtt{release_year > 2006}(\mathtt{film}))\)

\end{document}
```

Using `amsmath` and `\texttt` or `\mathtt` ensures the correct size for subscripts. Here you see the results: the difference is in you math symbols are treated: with `\texttt` you get the `>` in typewriter type and spaces are kept, with `\mathtt` you get the `>` symbol from the normal math font.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `\( ... \)` for the inline math mode

```
\begin{alltt}
\( \pi\sb{film_title}(\sigma\sb{release_year > 2006}(film)) \)
\end{alltt}
```

or with a correct fontsize setting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
\( \pi\sb{\text{film_title}}(\sigma\sb{\text{release_year > 2006}}(film)) \)
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

or without `alltt` and then as David suggested with `\_`

Comment: This doesn't produce subscripts in the typewriter font as requested.